# IOS: Reading RTF file with wrapping text

Tags: ios, textview, uilabel, uitextview, rtf

I read rtf file with code:

```
NSURL *rtfString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"Privacy Policy Imaspanse" withExtension:@"rtf"];
NSError *error;
NSMutableAttributedString *stringWithRTFAttributes = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithFileURL:rtfString options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.debugDescription);
} else {
    self.textLabel.attributedText = stringWithRTFAttributes;
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = [stringWithRTFAttributes size];
```

Problem is that long line do not wraps to the next line. How can I achieve it?
I need text that will be screen width and max height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
self.textLabel.attributedText = stringWithRTFAttributes;
[self.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
[self.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Comment: you use the AutoLayout? @adsjfkasjdflkasjdflkdalfjsdlf